# Connect white points in black image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a black background image with a curved shape consisting of white dots, points. The shape is a closed irregular curve. I have coordinates of these white points. I've been looking for a way to "connect" these dots, to close this line to make shape a closed curve. I can't use dilation and erosion because i need those existing location preserved.

Any ideas?

Example image:
[image]

Comment: Nice little problem, what have you tried? BTW your argument about dilation/erosion is not a good one, since you can always save your starting image (you even have the coordinates!)

Comment: What about converting the dots to x-y-coordinates, finding a distance matrix (like with pdist) and then connecting each point to it's 2 nearest neighbours?

Comment: I need just those coordinates, not the dilated ones I will get. I've tried "polyfit", "fit" and am now trying to do with lsqlin, which I saw someone try, but I am not getting the results I need.

Comment: Great idea Dan, simple but just might do!

Comment: Do you just need to generate/render an image with connected dots, or do you need to modify the image data itself?

Comment: Yes, it looks like what @Shai found.
Well, in my case it might be the same. I need a binary image with those dots connected. I guess more of a modified image data then.
http://i.imgur.com/WATxDqg.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you get the row,column coordinates in an ordered list:

1) Use `roipoly` to make a mask. From `roipoly` help:
`BW = roipoly(I, c, r)` returns the ROI specified by the polygon described by vectors c and r, which specify the column and row indices of each vertex, respectively. c and r must be the same size.

2) Use `edge` on the `BW` mask. That will give you a logical map with lines connecting the given points.

Alternatively) Use `impoly` to create an `imroi` instance, which is an object and has lots of methods (functions) that can be used on it. This is a more complicated approach that will result in the same thing, but you might be interested in it because it's neat.

Both approaches depend on you having the points in an ordered list.

Comment: I have coordinates of those points in a matrix, for a presumed 256 x 216 image. Will try this later. Thank you very much!

Comment: Works briliantly. Thank you very much Frederick!

Answer (score 2):

If the points are already in order,  it's very easy with complex numbers:

Define example data (a square):

```
x = [1 2 2 1];
y = [1 1 2 2];
```

Repeat first point (to create cycle), treat as complex, and plot:

```
plot(complex([x x(1)],[y y(1)]))
```

In the example, this gives the following figure.

[image]

If the points are not in order, they could be ordered with something similar to this, based on @Dan's idea of minimizing distance:

```
z = complex(x,y);
dist = tril(bsxfun(@(z1,z2) abs(z1-z2), z, z.')); % each pair only once ("tril")
dist(dist==0) = inf; % mark self-distances and repeated pairs as infinities
[~, ind] = min(dist);
```

For each point, `ind` gives the index of nearest point among those with larger index. With this information one should be able to order the points. It's not an easy problem, though. I'm not sure minimizing distance will always give the preferred shape (although it would in your example).